# I want to install freeglut3-dev package but this install removes the xserver (raring) without which my system can't run

Tags: 12.04, xserver

As mentioned in the title I want to install the `freeglut3-dev` library on my system in order to build an (ids camera) example application this requires the QtOpenGL and GL libraries.

But when I install the `freeglut3-dev` package it automatically removes the xserver related packages. In essence, `xserver-xorg-lts-raring`, `xserver-common-lts-raring` and `xorg`. This causes the (graphical) boot of my system to crash. I can then only fix this by reïnstalling the xserver (raring) related packages. But this then removes `freeglut3-dev` again.

Addition: I found that I also need `libqt4-opengl` which gives me the same problem.

How can I get both packages?

PS I installed bumblebee and have to boot using nomodeset

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this solution will work for you, but it worked for me - I had the same problem:

I downgraded my nvidia-driver to version 304.116 using additional drivers (jockey-gtk). Then I uninstalled mesa-common-dev and could install freeglut3-dev. Then I upgraded my nvidia-driver again to the latest version using additional drivers.

WARNING: I don't know if this could break something in your installation - as far as I know optimus support makes everything graphics-related a bit fragile...